# Receive JSON structured parameters in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

How to create a javascript function that will receive a JSON-like object as parameter, like this:

```
function foo() {
    //handle args somehow
}
```

And then be able to call it like this:

```
var someObj = {
    arg1: "some",
    arg2: "thing",
    options: {
        opt1: "asd",
        opt2: false
    }
}

foo(someObj);
```

Also, how to treat parameters that are not sent to the function (opt2 is omitted in this case):

```
var someObj = {
    arg1: "some",
    arg2: "thing",
    options: {
        opt1: "asd",
        //opt2: false
    }
}

foo(someObj);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I didn't knew how to search for it beacause I couldn't find it..

Comment: It's not "JSON-like". It's just an object. Access it like you would any other object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has nothing to do with JSON.  These are regular JavaScript object literals.

The normal thing to do, if your function is expecting parameters, is to define your function as such:

```
function foo(obj) {

}
```

From there, you can access the properties of that object like any other.

```
function foo(obj) {
  console.log(obj.options.opt1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define function like below:

```
 function foo(obj) {
        //handle args somehow
    }
```

and then use it `foo(someObj)` where someObj is your json.

if a property is missing in your object, then you handle it as :

```
if (obj.options.opt2)
{
    console.log('opt2 is available');
} 
else
{
    console.log('opt2 is not available');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to process the argument object like removing the keys which values are false, Then you can use the following method `foo` which takes object and returns object after removal.

```js
const foo = obj => ({
  ...obj,
  options: Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj.options).filter(([, value]) => value)
  )
});

var someObj = {
  arg1: "some",
  arg2: "thing",
  options: {
    opt1: "asd",
    opt2: false
  }
};

console.log(foo(someObj));
```